# Overflow Error that should not occur - Error: The datediff function resulted in an overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Using SSIS I am receive an error for a SQL task that I do not expect:

> Error: The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of
> dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use
> datediff with a less precise datepart.

My SQL script looks something like this:

```
SET @increment = 30;
-- other stuff...
    SELECT
        CD_AGENT,
        DATEADD(minute, IIF(MAX([DT_END_TIME]) > DATEADD(minute, CEILING(DATEDIFF(minute, 0, (MAX([DT_END_TIME]))) / CAST(@increment AS float)) * @increment, 0), @increment, 0), DATEADD(minute, CEILING(DATEDIFF(minute, 0, (MAX([DT_END_TIME]))) / CAST(@increment AS float)) * @increment, 0)) as DT_END_TIME,
      DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF(minute, 0, MIN([DT_START_TIME])) / @increment) * @increment, 0) as DT_START_TIME
    INTO #tempintervals
    FROM (
        SELECT
            CD_AGENT,
            MAX(DT_END_TIME) as DT_END_TIME,
            MIN(DT_START_TIME) as DT_START_TIME
      FROM qwe
      GROUP BY CD_AGENT
      UNION
      SELECT
            CD_AGENT,
            MAX(DT_END_TIME) as DT_END_TIME,
            MIN(DT_START_TIME) as DT_START_TIME
      FROM asd
      GROUP BY CD_AGENT
      UNION
      SELECT
            ia.CD_AGENT,
            MAX(i.DT_END_TIME) as DT_END_TIME,
            MIN(i.DT_START_TIME) as DT_START_TIME
      FROM yxc
      GROUP BY CD_AGENT) a
      GROUP BY CD_AGENT
      OPTION (maxdop 8);
-- other stuff...
```

I have checked the minimum and maximum value in the three tables qwe, asd, yxc like so:

```
  SELECT 
    MIN(DT_START_TIME) AS MinStartTime, 
    MAX(DT_END_TIME) AS MaxEndTime,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(DT_START_TIME), MAX(DT_END_TIME)) AS DiffInMinutes
FROM qwe
```

The highest interval was five years, why do I still receive the error? I am definitely expecting datediff to work, but not even datediff_big does work.
What else can I try? Is it perhaps because CEILING() cannot handle that number? Note that my result needs to be minute-precise.

Comment: The error above isn't for that SQL. If `DATEDIFF_BIG` were to generate that error it would state *"The **datediff_big** function resulted in an overflow."* `SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND,'0001-01-01','9999-12-31')` doesn't even generate an overflow error.

Comment: @ThomA sorry, it should be just overflow error haha.
Also, I accidently posted the code, that I tried after receiving the error, It may be datediff too.

Comment: So you get a `DATEDIFF_BIG` error too? Then you're working with nanoseconds somewhere.

Comment: @ThomA No no sorry for not being accurate enough. I have edited my post. The original code only has "datediff", but I receive that error: 
Error: The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

Interestling, if I use the datediff_big function instead, I receive exactly the same error (NOT "the datediff_big function resulted...")

Comment: Then you still had a `DATEDIFF` somewhere. Is `yxc` a `VIEW`? Take the time to create a [mre]; though when you do so, you'll probably fix the problem.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] i.e. reproduce the error in its simplest possible form and create the script plus data that produces the errors. We can only guess from looking at your query without seeing the data. And most likely in your efforts to create the example you will solve the problem.

Comment: "Something like this" isn't the code that produces the error, especially when that sorta-like code references table aliases that don't actually exist. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76504966/edit) your question to include the real code that causes the error. Using `datediff()` with minutes gives you an effective range of about `1900-01-01` through `5983-01-24`, so you probably have a math error somewhere in your real code.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution. My script contains a custom function that uses datediff as well. Changing the parameter from 9999 to 2100 worked out fine:
"... FROM [udf_TIMEINTERVALS](ISNULL(@start_time, '2100-12-31'), ISNULL(@end_time, '2100-12-31'), @interval, 30, @cd_agent);". Still thanks for your help :)